# Motor drive IC test

Tags: integrated-circuit, test

I have placed an order for a PCB where i am using two vnh7100as ICs to run two motors. I need to send the PCB makers a test file to test the ICs before putting them on. 
I have no idea what to send them. I looked up online and datasheet to figure out if there are any test methods mentioned but couldnt find. 
Could anyone help me figure out how such ICs can be tested. I need to make sure the current sensing module and the logic inputs and outputs work.

Comment: Much unclear. Are you talking about an ICT production test?

Comment: Have you asked them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing ICs **before** soldering them on a PCB is **very uncommon**. I almost dare to say: **No one does that**.

Testing of the ICs is done at the factory before the ICs are packaged to be shipped.

To test an IC you often need very expensive equipment and engineers to setup the test. Also, only the IC manufacturer knows all the details of the chip, for example any (secret) testmodes it has. In practice you or the PCB manufacturer cannot do a full test unless the IC is extremely simple (like an opamp or some simple logic function).

Imagine if what the cost would be if a phone manufacturer has to test all the many ICs which go into a smartphone. Some ICs are so complex that developing a test costs a small fortune. So the ICs are not tested by the PCB/Phone manufacturer, instead the IC manufacturer tests them.

In your case you have to ask the PCB makers what they really want. If they insist on testing the IC themselves then they need to explain why that is needed.